# Which function called when click on leaflet draw controls(poly,rect etc) : leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I am working on leaflet application.Where i also use my custom draw controls as well as leaflet draw controls.

Lately, i needed to unbind my custom controls when leaflet draw controls clicked.

Suppose i have a custom control as in script, then how can i unload that function that is :

> map.on('click', wallPlace);

Script(in case of clarification)

```
L.easyButton('<img src="assets/img/wallicon.png" title="Draw Wall">', function () {
                    map.on('click', wallPlace);
                    polylineWall = new L.Polyline([], { color: 'yellow' });
                }).addTo(map);
function wallPlace(){//some stuff}
```

I have been searching and inspecting the events in event listner, but couldn't find any.

As i am new to javascript, some understanding problem persists.If someone know about that please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind events using `on` and unbind them using the `off` method. This is all perfectly well described in the referenceguide on the official Leaflet site:

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events

If you want to know if someone is starting to draw or edit with Leaflet.Draw, you can use the `draw:drawstart` and `draw:editstart` events:

```
map.on('draw:drawstart', function () {
    map.off('click', mapClickHandler);
});
```

- https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#drawdrawstart
- https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#draweditstart

Comment: thanks for reply, i meant when i click on my custom control then its 'on',,, but now when i click on draw controls, my custom control should be 'off'..so where to put that 'off' method